# I can't boot Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit on Mac download

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit, mac

I've been trying to replace my MacOS in my iMac with Ubuntu 14.04.

Initially, I downloaded the standard 64-bit and installed using a USB drive. Although the install says it's successful, I can't seem to boot it after removing the USB drive.

If I try to reinstall it using the drive, it seems to be able to detect that Ubuntu has already been installed. I'm planning on trying to use the 64-bit Mac install to see if that solves the problem but the link seems to be broken.

Anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be ubuntu install grub to the usb drive so you can't boot. when choosing partition to install, it has an option to choose which partition will get grub install on. choose your sda, not sdx (usb drive)

Answer (score -1):

I get a 404 error too.

You can download it here:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/