# cannot download needed version. (mac)

Tags: downloads

i can't download the mac version of ubuntu, the normal 64-bit version downloads, but when I try to download the mac 64-bit version it comes up with a "404 not found" message.
how can i fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/451003/i-cant-boot-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-on-mac-download

Comment: @LouisMatthijssen I pretty sure that's not the right dupe.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problems downloading from these URLs:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/release/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso (desktop)

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64+mac.iso (server)